# JsonTypeInfo not shown in response whit Pageable

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, jackson2

I have an abstract class

```
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "_type", visible = true, include = As.EXISTING_PROPERTY)
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
    @JsonSubTypes({
       @Type(value = B.class, name = "B"),
       ...
    })
    public abstract class A {
      ...
    }
```

and one of subclasses

```
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
@JsonTypeName("B")
public class B extends A {
  ...
}
```

When I want to create one entity I need to specify "_type" property. Which is perfectly good. But when I want a list of A-s, I can't get property "_type" specified in JSON response.

I've tried multiple solutions but cannot find the right way to do it. 
I've tried to add "_type" property with transactional, tried to add `"include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY"`. But still nothing.

Of course for everything I have only one controller for class A.

Can anyone tell me how to get "_type" in get response and other responses?

tnx

Comment: I guess your controller method is something like `List<A> loadA(...)` with some `Spring` annotations. Does not it? I noticed type information is skipped for generics when `List` is an root object. Try to create `ListAResponse` class and wrap this `List` using `List<A> aList;` property. After that try to change your controller method to `ListAResponse loadA(...)`. Should work. Which version of `Jackson` and `Spring` do you use?

Comment: my return type of method in the controller is Page<A> with Pageable request. Spring version is 2.0.6 and Jackson version is 2.9.9

Comment: I forget to tell you that all work with the list. But when I enter Page and pageable, then I can't get type in the response.

Comment: any solution? I face this issue too

Comment: Unfortunately no. There is a possibility to write an aspect that will paste _type on all entities, but this is not the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a bug, not sure where though. Anyway, I have found a workaround for it today.

```
@GetMapping
public Page<MyObject> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
   Page<MyObject> page = ...;
   return new PageImpl<>(page.getContent(), pageable, page.getTotalElements()) {};
}
```

Note that the new instance of anonymous class extending `PageImpl` is being returned here (not a new instance of `PageImpl`) to prevent type erasure.